# What if a convert later finds out he was already Jewish?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

If someone converts to Judaism, but later credible evidence is found that he was already Jewish (say, due to a distant matrilineal ancestress), is he still treated as a convert for halachic purposes?

Does the conversion certificate say "not valid if he turns out to be already Jewish"? Or is it "Once converted, always converted"?

Comment: Why would he not be treated as jewish if valid evidence is discovered. Note that the question is just as valid if it involves his mother's mother. A farther ancestor might require a *conversion misafek*. I actually knew someone who converted because of a doubt.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. In terms of halachic requirements, how is a convert different from any other Jew? Can you specify which areas of halacha he may be treated differently?

Comment: @DanF a female convert can't marry a kohen.

Comment: **conversion certificate** ??? That's a Modern Addition, is it exists at all. Irrelevant to halacha.

Comment: "Converting" someone who was really born Jewish, is an exercise in futility.

Comment: a jew cannot convert to judaism